# Python: Accept connections into a list, and have the user select a specific socket to write to?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python: Accept connections into a list, and have the user select a specific socket to write to?

I want to program a simple Python server that accepts incoming connections, stores them into a list, and has a user-interface that lets the user select which socket to write to.

So, while the server accepts new connections and prints received data to screen, the user should have a UI like:

```
> select 2 # select connection 2
> helloworld # writes 'helloworld' to the socket
```

How can I do this using threads or subprocesses? (what is the best approach?)

Bonus: How can I do so, that received data don't mess with the UI prompt?

This is my code using `select.select()`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import sys
import select
import socket

TCP_IP = '0.0.0.0'
TCP_PORT = 80
BUF_SZ = 1024

sock_list = []

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((TCP_IP,TCP_PORT))
server.listen(10)

inputs = [server]
outputs = []

while True:
    read_socks, write_socks, error_socks = select.select(inputs, outputs, inputs)
    for sock in read_socks:
        if sock is server:
            conn,addr = server.accept()
            inputs.append(conn)
            print('Connection %s' % conn)
        else:
            data = sock.recv(BUF_SZ)
            print(data)
    for sock in write_socks:
        None
```

Answer (score 0):

To use threading you can simply wait on `socket.accept()` and when you receive a new connection handle it using a new thread. A sample code can be like this:

```
import socket
import sys
import threading


def worker(conn, ip, port, max_buffer_size=4096):
    print('accepting connection from ip={} and port={}'.
        format(ip, port, conn))
    data = conn.recv(max_buffer_size)
    # Do something
    conn.close()



def init_server():
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
    server_socket.listen(PARALLEL_CONNECTIONS)
    return server_socket


def run():
    try:
        s = init_server()
        print('successfully created server socket.')
    except Exception as e:
        print('failed to create socket because {}'.format(e))
        sys.exit()

    while True:
        clientsocket, addr = s.accept()
        ip, port = str(addr[0]), str(addr[1])
        t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(clientsocket, ip, port,))
        t.start()
```